# Proving Taylor's Theorem with Lagrange Remainder

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm familiar with the proof of Taylor's theorem that uses integration by parts. This approach also uses continuous integration but not by IBP. I get the Lagrange form of the remainder instead of the integral form of the remainder. I may be overlooking something since this approach seems more straightforward than integration by parts (at least to me). I teach high school AP calculus and have been thinking about an approach that students will be able to grasp based on prior theorems, namely MVT and FTC.

Consider an $(n+1)$-times differentiable function $f(t)$ on $[a,x]$.

By MVT, there exists a $t=c$ $\in (a,x)$ such that
$$\displaystyle f^{(n+1)}(c)=\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(a)}{x-a} \implies f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(a)+f^{(n+1)}(c)(x-a)$$ Integrating on $[a,x]$ with respect to $t$ , $$\int_a^x \! f^{(n)}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t=\int_a^x \!\left( f^{(n)}(a)+f^{(n+1)}(c)(t-a) \, \right)\mathrm{d}t$$ Using FTC on the left hand side, $$f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(a)=f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f^{(n+1)}(c)(x-a)^2$$
Solving for $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ and integrating again,$$\int_a^x \! f^{(n-1)}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t=\int_a^x \!\left( f^{(n-1)}(a)+f^{(n)}(a)(t-a)+\frac{1}{2}f^{(n+1)}(c)(t-a)^2 \, \right)\mathrm{d}t$$
Again using FTC on the left,$$f^{(n-2)}(x)-f^{(n-2)}(a)=f^{(n-1)}(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^2+\frac{1}{6}f^{(n+1)}(c)(x-a)^3\implies$$ $$f^{(n-2)}(x)=f^{(n-2)}(a)+f^{(n-1)}(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^2+\frac{1}{6}f^{(n+1)}(c)(x-a)^3$$
We can continue to integrate like this until we arrive at $f(x)$ on the left,$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2!}f''(a)(x-a)^2+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(a)(x-a)^3+...+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)}$$

From a teaching standpoint, would you recommend this approach or should I stick to the traditional method that presupposes a power series and solves for the coefficients? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your final remark confuses me. Solving for coefficients has nothing to do with the error term. My favorite proof is just applying the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem repeatedly. See Spivak’s *Calculus* for this proof. In 15 or more times of teaching this material, I never taught the integral form of the remainder.

Comment: Let me add that I envisioned this process when I was thinking about the (n+1)th derivative and thought "what if we replace this function with the average of the function on the interval [a,x]?" Since the area under the curves are equal on the interval, then why not successively integrate starting with a constant function. This has the advantage that if start by integrating a constant I get a linear function, then a quadratic the next time I integrate, then a cubic etc. It seemed feasible, so after writing it down I posted it here.

Comment: Your proof is not valid, as $c$ depends on $x$, which then varies when you integrate.

Comment: Ted Shifrin, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I understand because I am considering x as the right endpoint of my interval of integration with respect to t. I see that the c value changes as this endpoint is varied, but I am using x here as a fixed endpoint, where c is constant on a fixed interval (the average value of the function). Just trying to understand. Thanks.

Comment: No, you rewrite your first line replacing $x$ with $t$, and $c$ depends on $t$.

Comment: I understand that the value c depends on x, but I don't see how this changes the integral on my 2nd line. I think your point is that I cannot treat f^(n+1)(c) as a constant in the integration. But for any given upper bound of integration on [a,x] there exists a constant f^(n+1)(c) value that depends only on that upper bound x, and is independent of the variable of integration t. So I am treating f^(n+1)(c) as a constant when I integrate. I know a correct result doesn't justify the proof, but the results lead me to think there is validity to the overall approach which may need corrections.

Comment: How is an unknown function [remember that you don't even know that $c_t$ varies continuously with $t$] times $(t-a)$ going to integrate to $\frac12 f^{n+1}(c)(x-a)^2$? The same problem recurs at every single step. I am extremely dubious, but I'll listen to a valid attempt :P ... In the meantime, if you're going to prove something in class (which most high school AP courses do not do), then follow the iterated Cauchy Mean Value Theorem approach. It has the right spirit, is very straightforward, and avoids integrals entirely.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I don't prove theorems for my students in general, but for those who are motivated and wish to explore proofs I like to provide them outside of class. I would not show this idea (yet) but I am developing a more heuristic argument for the more ambitious students. I will look into the iterated Cauchy Mean Value Theorem. Thank you.

Comment: I personally think that generalizing the Mean Value Theorem is precisely the right heuristic, and that the integral remainder proofs can be tricky and slick, but really obscure the important ideas. And hardly ever get applied, either.